# How to leave my training process running after I exit the container and ssh?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, shell, amazon-ec2

I'm training a model on AWS, and my workflow is:

1. Connect to the EC2 instance via `ssh`
2. Start the Docker container if not running already
3. `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`
4. `python train.py`

I can use `Ctrl+Z` to put the Python process in the background. However, I cannot exit the container shell, because the training process is attached to it. I assume it will also exit if I disconnect from ssh entirely (laptop shuts down, I close the terminal, etc.)

I thought that running `python train.py &` would fix it, but the training process is still stopped.

What's the best/most common way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Run the training process as the main process in the container instead of starting it after exec-ing into it.

Comment: @rdas ah good idea. I didn't set up any monitoring however, I'd still like to know how to do it with my current workflow, unless it's an otherwise bad idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach won't work, because when you exit  the container shell the Python process will be killed.

You can either:

1. Run `docker exec` with the `-d` detached mode:

   ```
   docker exec -it -d <container_name> python train.py
   ```
2. Configure your docker container to have the Python script as the entrypoint:

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT ["python", "train.py"]
   ```

   then you can `docker run` the container with the `-d` detached mode.

Comment: Thanks. I assume this means I would have to rebuild the image? I'd like to avoid that, can I just add some arguments to the `docker run` command?

Comment: @corazza see my updated answer; if you don't want to rebuild you can go with option 1